# macOS "./configure: No such file or directory" problem

Tags: bash, sphinx, configure, macos-mojave

When I try to install Sphinx with this guide

```
./configure --with-pgsql --with-mysql #from guide
make #from guide
sudo make install #from guide
```

**./configure**

```
 -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

**$ autoreconf --install**

```
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not excellent solution (because without mysql), but working (as all in programming world).

1) `brew remove mysql`

2) `brew install mysql@5.7` (I don't know why, but it is working only with this version)

3) download [sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.11-release.tar.gz](http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.11-release.tar.gz) and extract and `cd` to it

4) `./configure --with-pgsql --without-mysql` and `make` and `sudo make install`

It is working for me, because I need postgresql first of all

Comment: If you need MySQL v8 support, Sphinx v3.1.1 is what you should use - it's the first (and currently only) release that works with MySQL v8.

Comment: You saved my week! I've been struggling with this for a couple of days already. Installing 2.2.11 without MySQL (but having 5.7 installed) made the trick.

Comment: I’m happy that helped you. I were fighting with this problem too long as you

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the `./configure` command within the Sphinx source code folder? These instructions are for *compiling* Sphinx.

It's worth noting that the latest (v3.x) Sphinx releases aren't available as source code, only as pre-compiled binaries. So if that's what you've downloaded, you'll want to copy the files in `./bin` - which would include `indexer` and `searchd` - into a location within your PATH (I would suggest `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: I have source `sphinx-2.2.10-release-osx10.10-x86_64` And I try to start ./configure inside of it: `$ cd sphinx-2.2.10-release-osx10.10-x86_64` then `$ ./configure` and got error  `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: I'd recommend 2.2.11 as the latest of the 2.2.x releases - here's a direct link to the source code: http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.11-release.tar.gz - does the `./configure --with-pgsql --with-mysql` command work in that?

Comment: Yes. Now it runs ./configure, but raises error `checking MySQL include files... configure: error: missing include files.

******************************************************************************
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.` I tried both --with-mysql=.. and --with-mysql-includes=...